# Using frozen/cooked frozen blood in black pudding

Tags: sausages

I am having a hell of a time trying to track down blood in the US for black pudding. None of our local processors can provide it, several butchers are claiming it's illegal to sell (not true, but you have to be licensed at the abbatoire). I haven't been able to find a place that will sell dried pigs blood over the internet AND can ship.

The only option I've found so far is frozen pig blood from a local meat plant (they do NOT sell fresh, only frozen), or a small asian market (they ONLY sell coagulated pig blood that has been cooked).

Can these be used interchangably or is it an absolute requirement that the blood be fresh?

Comment: Not sure how true this is but I'll say it any way. My butcher seems to think the use of blood is rare now a days. Instead they use plasma. Which can be dried into a powder mix along with spices. This mix then only requires fat to be added and then cooked in skins.

Comment: where do you live, Matthew?  I am able to get pig's blood from my local meat processor when I've had a pig butchered.  I just have to ask for it ahead of time, so that they will save it.

Comment: I've had stew made with blood at a Filipino place in San Francisco.  I'm guessing that most butchers wouldn't carry it unless they could sell it, as it'd have been drained at the slaughterhouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The frozen blood (once it is thawed) would be the better option.  I would not consider the cooked and coagulated product to be interchangeable with the thawed product.

Answer (score 0):

what DOUG says is correct.I used to be a chef,and I had to make our own Black Pudding,every fortnight.We used to get dried plasma mix in bulk,.I can see no reason why you could not get this exported to the USA,as it is totally non-volatile,or offensive in any way you care to think of...
Get some in,and teach those yanks the joy of B.P !!!!